# Filter file with awk and keep header in output

Tags: awk, filter, header

I have following CSV file:

```
a,b,c,d
x,1,1,1
y,1,1,0
z,1,0,0
```

I want to keep lines that add up more than 1, so I execute this awk command:

```
awk -F "," 'NR > 1{s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; if (s>1)print}' file
```

And obtain this:

```
x,1,1,1
y,1,1,0
```

How can I do the same but retain the first line (header)?

Comment: You need to add NR==1; before NR > 1 in your command.. like below -

awk -F "," 'NR==1; NR > 1{s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; if (s>1)print}'

Comment: @fibar, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ awk -F "," 'NR==1; NR > 1{s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; if (s>1)print}' file
a,b,c,d
x,1,1,1
y,1,1,0
```

Comment: can also use `awk -F, 'NR > 1{s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i} s>1 || NR==1' file`

Comment: Nice alternative @Sundeep, a more idiomatic version I would say.

Comment: What does the NR ==1 mean. I understand that NR > 1 means not to carry the function on the first line.

Comment: @HKJ3, In the posted answer, `NR == 1;` means to do the default action for the first line. It is equivalent in this context to `NR == 1 { print }`.  In other words, print the header (line 1) no matter what. For all lines after the header, print according to the logic given.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's only 0s and 1s:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || gsub(/1/, "1") > 1' file
a,b,c,d
x,1,1,1
y,1,1,0
```